# Обновление сайта на тестовом сервере без перезагрузки apache

Tags: python, django, apache2

Начинаю изучать python+django, и настроил себе для тестов виртуалку с apache2 и postgresql.

Столкнулся с тем, что при изменении контента сайта нужно перезагружать сервер, чтоб изменения стали видны - например меняешь текст страницы генерируемой котроллером hello c "Hello World" на "бла бла бла", и чтоб увидеть изменение на странице нужно не только обновить собственно страницу в браузере, но еще и перезагрузить сервер перед этим.

Что может быть причиной такого поведения сервера, и как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, всё, разобрался. Всё-таки удалось найти рецепт, хотя до этого гугл предлагал инфу только про ajax запросы.
В конфиге апача нужно прописать директиву

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 1
```

Тогда на каждый новый запрос будет запускаться новый интерпритатор, и соответственно код страницы тоже будет грузиться заново.

Answer (score 0):

Для разработки проще использовать ./manage runserver .
Оно и перезагружаться умеет при изменении .py файлов.